# Extracting company name and domain from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the name and address of the company. I want to extract the company name(Maps corrects the company name if I go wrong with the spelling) and the domain name. But I am not getting that response in the json. I get latitudes and longitudes, formatted addresses and so on. What do I do?

EDIT:
This is a part of my code (addr is the company address like 'Company Name, Street, CIty, Country')

```
response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addr)
resp_json_payload = response.json()
```

In this response, I am not getting the domain name and company name.

Comment: What request do you send? Places text search? Places details? Something else? Please post your request in the question.

Comment: Thanks @xomena. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request in your example is Geocoding API.

You should use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) in order to get business info.

Use text search to find a place ID and place details to get detailed information about the place.

For example, I search 'CEM Can Ricart, Carrer de Sant Oleguer, 10 08001 Barcelona'

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=CEM%20Can%20Ricart%2C%20Carrer%20de%20Sant%20Oleguer%2C%2010%2008001%20Barcelona&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This gives me a place ID `ChIJ99uZFlmipBIRoofrsnuoj9g`

Now I can get detailed info for this place that will contain name, phone and web page of the place

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ99uZFlmipBIRoofrsnuoj9g&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The result is like in my screenshot
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, so I will need to get the PlaceID first and then use that to get relevant information. Is there a way to get it done with 1 API request only? I have around 10 mil requests to send and sending 2 API requests per record will be very expensive for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Also in the Geocoding API I am using, it doesnt ask me for a API Key. How is it working inspite of that?

Comment: I think it is not possible to get detailed information in one step. So first you need a Place ID and after that request details. Geocoding requests without API keys are working at the moment, in this case the usage quota is calculated based on your IP address. If you share an IP address with other users you might have less than 2500 daily requests.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Google API that does exactly what you need: the Client location API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

You could simply use the Google Search API and some logic to find only businesses (http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/)

Comment: Can you elaborate of which Goggle API to use?Can you elaborate more on this - "You could simply use the Google Search API and some logic to find only businesses". The link you sent seems a little vague to me. Thanks!